# Connection Request Timed out issue again come after increase Max Pool Size in ASP.NET ORACLE

Tags: asp.net, oracle, iis-7, iis-express, oracle12c

I have running online application.Minimum 100 user daily login my application.Daily 2 are 3 times come connection request timed out issue.then restart IIS solve this problem.

I increased Max Pool Size=9999.Min Pool Size =1;But no use increase Max Pool Size.after connection open ,properly dispose all connection in my code

Any other reason for come connection request timed out issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling OracleConnection.ClearAllPools() when your done with a connection and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: This method does't work. connection.open(); next line  oracleconnection.ClearAllPools(); then connection passing database and i can retrive data. So ClearAllPools method does't work.

Comment: Calling ClearAllPools will not close your connection. Once ClearAllPools has been called, the connection will be discarded when you call Close on the connection.